# Control a microwave from my computer?

Tags: usb, cpu, microprocessor, control

Is there anyways I can take apart a microwave (any kind) and some how plug it into my computer and control it from my computer? Where to start... where to start...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that by "Microwave" you mean a domestic microwave oven.

(1) The easy and obvious way is to access the existing controller via the keypad - either by using transmission gates across the keyboard matrix - which is easy and fast to achieve, or by simulating the key scan results that the onboard microcontroller sees.

It's quite likely that as few as 2 x CD4051 transmission gates would allow keyscan access - but this is not certain. Rows to 8 or less inputs of 1st CD4051m, columns to 8 or less inputs, join outputs. [CD4051 datasheet here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4051b.pdf).

Similar to this but join output of both multiplexers.

[image]

You'd be dong this blind so could get lost.
 Monitoring keyboard beeper allows checking progress.
 If magnetron does not behave as desired you can reset it.

(2)  Or - easy but more technical and higher risk - drive present microcontroller pcb outputs.

Be **SURE** not to bypass any safety interlocks.

**DEATH OR SERIOUS INJURY CAN BE ACHIEVED WHEN DOING THIS**

---

SAFETY INTERLOCKS:

Microwave ovens have more safety interlocks to prevent uncontrolled operation than do most other consumer devices.
 There is a reason for this.
 Things that chop, slice, grind, mangle and compress can be very nasty indeed and the reason for fitting the interlocks to stop them doing their stuff on you or your family, friends or random strangers is usually obvious enough.

A Microwave oven can deal invisible death or blindness or other injuries without advance warning if it is permitted to operate when in an unsafe condition. I have looked at some interlocks used and was impressed at the steps they go to in a consumer product to foil the typical screwdriver poking, microswitch taping interlock overriding cowboy.

My prior home oven had dual microswitch interlocks on the door catch that also required lock A to have fitted home before lock B could lock AND lock A worked in such a way that if you pushed in a straight bar / screwdriver etc it would fail to lock - you needed the tip of the hooked door catch to travel into position and then drop down before interlock A was closed and interlock B was potentially able to close.

If you value your sight or life or those of anyone who may approach within about 5 metres (guesstimate) of the device then DO NOT DISABLE OR BYPASS THE INTERLOCKS.
I say 5 metres as the about worst case, apart from just boiling your head [ :-( ], is probably to crack the door slightly to form a slot radiator and getting quite a tight 2.4 Ghz beam. I'd guess that by about 5 metres away inverse square law and unidealities would probably let you get away with feeling warmer than expected. But I'd not be volunteering in any tests to see if 5 metres was "safe enough" [tm].

Comment: Sweet! I was thinking about just manually installing some relays where the buttons would normally complete the circuit then just writing some quick software to simulate button presses where I need them! I really don't want to mess the the micro controller hehe! Thanks for your answer, very insightful!

Comment: > DEATH OR SERIOUS INJURY CAN BE ACHIEVED WHEN DOING THIS.  There had better be a really good reason why you want to do this.

Answer (score 2):

The last stage of microwave oven controller is just a relay or a triac. Power is controlled by varying on and off timings in a 30 seconds period (15 seconds on/15 seconds off is 50% of oven maximum power).

The easier way (clearly IMHO) is to ditch the original oven controller and drive directly the relay or the triac from your computer with an appropriate circuit (via RS232 or USB)

And yes... DEATH OR SERIOUS INJURY CAN BE ACHIEVED WHEN DOING THIS

Comment: Even more so this way than most other ways as it tends to implicitly bypass the safety interlocks. ie while you have not mentioned them and while they COULD still be in circuit the description would tend the casual reader to overlook that they exist AND are a very good idea [tm].

Comment: @RussellMcMahon You're totally right here. I can say that in every MWO that I opened/repaired the safety systems were electrically located after the relay/triac (so they doesn't rely on the controller electronics), but this is not a rule. A MWO is a device that could kill even when powered off and disconnected from the mains. This should be a big banner :-)

Comment: Death can even be achieved with your own relay? Just simulating button presses form your computer? I'm still leaving all of their safety precautions on.

Comment: Just touching the HV capacitor could kill you. So, if you works with attention, simulating buttons presses *should* be safe...

Answer (score 0):

My inclination would be to find an old-fashioned microwave oven with a "dial" controller.  On many of those, if one sets a time on the dial while the microwave is disconnected from the mains, the microwave will start operating when mains is applied (the timer itself may or may not run without power; some are spring-wound, while others are motor-operated).  Depending upon your exact requirements, you may be able to control the microwave without having to open the case or modify it at all.